# Why when using SUM(field) the total is duplicated for different items?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that needs the total parts sold.
But because of the name of the part, it doubles the line.
How could I solve this problem of doubling the amount?

PS. vendorNum = model code
within the model has N variations. But as I need the sold quantity of the model, I removed the variations.

```
 SELECT T0.VendorNum
     ,T2.FrgnName 
     ,T4.Descr
     , T3.CardName
     , YEAR(T1.DocDate)[DATA]
     ,SUM(T0.Quantity)[QTDADE]
FROM RDR1 T0 -- (T0)SALES BODY
    JOIN ORDR T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry --(T1)SALES HEADER
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT SuppCatNum, CardCode, FrgnName FROM OITM) T2 ON T2.SuppCatNum = T0.VendorNum -- (T2)ITEMS
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CardCode, CardName  FROM OCRD) T3 ON T3.CardCode = T2.CardCode -- (T3)TABLE SUPPLIER
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT IndexID, TableID, FieldID, Descr FROM UFD1) T4 ON T0.U_Tipo = T4.IndexID AND TableID = 'RDR1' AND FieldID = 12   --(T4)USER DEFINED TABLE
WHERE T0.DocDate >= '20200101' AND T0.DocDate <= '20201231'
    AND T3.CardCode = 'F00045'
    AND T0.VendorNum = 'CU03E'
    AND T1.CANCELED = 'N'
    AND ((T0.TargetType > 0 AND T0.LineStatus = 'C') OR (T0.LineStatus = 'O'))
GROUP BY T0.VendorNum, T2.FrgnName,T3.CardName, T4.Descr, YEAR(T1.DocDate)
ORDER BY T0.VendorNum
```

RESULT:

| VendorNum | FrgnName | Descr | CardName | DATE | QTDADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CU03E | DECORATIVE CUSHION | Capa | PAOLA LENTI SRL | 2020 | 189.000000 |
| CU03E | DECORATIVE CUSHION**S** | Capa | PAOLA LENTI SRL | 2020 | 189.000000 |

But if I hide the `T2.FrgnName` field it brings me right. The problem I need the description.
And that at least disappears separately.

but I can't use logic right now

I hid the field and it worked. but I need that visible field.

```
SELECT T0.VendorNum
    /* ,T2.FrgnName */
     ,T4.Descr
     , T3.CardName
     , YEAR(T1.DocDate)[DATA]
     ,SUM(T0.Quantity)[QTDADE]
FROM RDR1 T0
    JOIN ORDR T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT SuppCatNum, CardCode, FrgnName FROM OITM) T2 ON T2.SuppCatNum = T0.VendorNum
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CardCode, CardName  FROM OCRD) T3 ON T3.CardCode = T2.CardCode
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT IndexID, TableID, FieldID, Descr FROM UFD1) T4 ON T0.U_Tipo = T4.IndexID AND TableID = 'RDR1' AND FieldID = 12   
WHERE T0.DocDate >= '20200101' AND T0.DocDate <= '20201231'
    AND T3.CardCode = 'F00045'
    AND T0.VendorNum = 'CU03E'
    AND T1.CANCELED = 'N'
    AND ((T0.TargetType > 0 AND T0.LineStatus = 'C') OR (T0.LineStatus = 'O'))
GROUP BY T0.VendorNum, /*T2.FrgnName,*/ T3.CardName, T4.Descr, YEAR(T1.DocDate)
ORDER BY T0.VendorNum
```

**RESULT**

| VendorNum | FrgnName | Descr | CardName | DATE | QTDADE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CU03E | NULL | PAOLA LENTI SRL | 2020 | 128.000000 |  |
| CU03E | Capa | PAOLA LENTI SRL | 2020 | 378.000000 |  |

Comment: Aliases like `a` is for `Customer` and `b` is for `Account`, or `t1` is for `Purchase` and `t2` is for `Transaction` aren't helpful for you or others that want to read your code. Use meaningful and *consistent* aliases for your objects. I suggest a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: *Consumable* sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: The solution will be to fix your description or don't include description.

Comment: Since you don't specify any logic to pick one description over the other (and perhaps you don't care), just throw `Max()` around that column and remove it from your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: The solution was to play for the application.
I would have liked to have exported to .xlsx, but there would have been a lot of duplicate lines.
In this case, the best scenario would be to treat via application, where I can do the sum without using `SUM()`